# Filtrar objetos dentro de um array com hash

Tags: javascript, objetos, filter

Eu estou criando um programinha em JS de controle de plantação e na função add(), quero adicionar um filtro para verificar se aquele hash (name) já existe, porém, não estou conseguindo:

```
let data = [];
let name = {};
data[name];

function menu(){
let option = Number(prompt('1- adicionar  2- apagar  3- exibir  0- sair'));
switch(option){
    case 1: add(); break;
    case 2: break;
    case 3: break;
    default: return 0;
}
}

function add(){
name = prompt('Nome:');
let day = prompt('Dia:');
let mouth = prompt('Mês:');
var exists = data.filter(function(obj){
    return 'name' in obj['name'] != name;
});
console.log(exists);
if (data[name]!=exists){
    alert(`${name} adicionado!`)
    data[name] = {name: name, date:{day:day, mouth:mouth}};
    menu();
}
else if(prompt(`${name} já existe! quer atualizar? S ou N`)!='S'){
    alert('voltando ao menu...');
    menu();
}
data[name] = {name: name, date:{day:day, mouth:mouth}};
}

menu();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algumas coisas no seu código não estão corretas, tais como:

- A forma como está a fazer a filtragem;
- A verificação (`if`) se o novo item já existe;
- A forma como está a adicionar ao array.

Alterei estes pontos no seu código para que funcione como pretende. Porém, ainda há espaço para melhoramentos no seu código.

```js
let data = [];
let name = {};
data[name];

function menu(){
let option = Number(prompt('1- adicionar  2- apagar  3- exibir  0- sair'));
switch(option){
    case 1: add(); break;
    case 2: break;
    case 3: break;
    default: return 0;
}
}

function add(){
name = prompt('Nome:');
let day = prompt('Dia:');
let mouth = prompt('Mês:');
var exists = data.filter(function(obj){
    return obj['name'] === name;
}).length > 0;

if (!exists){
    alert(`${name} adicionado!`)
    data.push({name: name, date:{day:day, mouth:mouth}});
    menu();
}
else if(prompt(`${name} já existe! quer atualizar? S ou N`)!='S'){
    alert('voltando ao menu...');
    menu();
}
data[name] = {name: name, date:{day:day, mouth:mouth}};
}

menu();
```

Comment: muito obrigado cara, eu estou recém aprendendo esse conteúdo, vou dar uma analisada no código